# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when running function

Tags: python, numpy, audio, fft

First question on here! I am getting a Type Error when running this code:

```
def fourier(sample):
mag = []
fft_data = np.fft.fft(sample)  # Returns real and complex value pairs
fft_data.flatten

for i in range(len(fft_data)//2):
    r =  fft_data[i].real**2
    j =  fft_data[i].imag**2
    mag.append(round(math.sqrt(r+j),2))

return mag
```

Output:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: math.sqrt only works with ONE number. `fft_data.flatten` does not work inplace

Comment: Adding up to hpaulj: you probably need `()` as well, so say `fft_data = fft_data.flatten()`

Although it is hard to say, if we do not have a reproducible example - in other words, you should provide an attempt of calling your `fourier()` function

Comment: Try using `np.round` and `np.sqrt`

Comment: And please, include stacktrace